# Configuring SSL in zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Can somebody help me to sort out the SSL connection to zookeeper,my questions is How to configure 
CLIENT_JVMFLAGS in zkCli.cmd file in windows.

Ref :https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ZOOKEEPER/ZooKeeper+SSL+User+Guide

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

Set CLIENT JVMFLAGS at terminal by exporting exact as mentioned in that website(Before starting zkCli). (Don't get confused about zkCli, which is "zk command line" not "zkclient")

```
Client VM Args:

-Dzookeeper.clientCnxnSocket=org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNetty

-Dzookeeper.client.secure=true

-Dzookeeper.ssl.keyStore.location=C:/OpenSSL/bin/1KeyStore.jks

-Dzookeeper.ssl.keyStore.password=yourpass

-Dzookeeper.ssl.trustStore.location=C:/OpenSSL/bin/1truststore.jks

-Dzookeeper.ssl.trustStore.password=yourpass"
```

For more, Follow these steps to make connection and everything you need:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-2125

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the zkEnv.sh

```
export SERVER_JVMFLAGS="
-Dzookeeper.serverCnxnFactory=org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory
-Dzookeeper.ssl.keyStore.location=/root/zookeeper/ssl/testKeyStore.jks 
-Dzookeeper.ssl.keyStore.password=testpass 
-Dzookeeper.ssl.trustStore.location=/root/zookeeper/ssl/testTrustStore.jks 
-Dzookeeper.ssl.trustStore.password=testpass"
```

Also you might need to add more Heap.

Follow this page:

[ZooKeeper SSL User Guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ZOOKEEPER/ZooKeeper+SSL+User+Guide)